# R tidyverse, Reshaping data to one row per subject, but several columns are affected

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a sample data frame like this:

```
sample2<-structure(list(`Full Name` = c("Smith, Jane", NA, NA, NA, 
                           NA, NA, "Doe, John", NA, NA, NA), `Age 
           (Y)` = c("24", 
                    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "22", NA, NA, NA), Gender = c("F", NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, NA), `Procedure Performed 
           (ICD9 Code)` = c("34.04 INSERTION OF INTERCOSTAL CATHETER FOR DRAINAGE", 
                            "86.59 CLOSURE OF SKIN AND SUBCUTANEOUS TISSUE OTHER SITES", 
                            "87.03 COMPUTERIZED AXIAL TOMOGRAPHY OF HEAD", "88.01 COMPUTERIZED AXIAL TOMOGRAPHY OF ABDOMEN", 
                            "87.41 COMPUTERIZED AXIAL TOMOGRAPHY OF THORAX", NA, "96.04 INSERTION OF ENDOTRACHEAL TUBE", 
                            "57.94 INSERTION OF INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER", "99.29 INJECTION OR INFUSION OF OTHER THERAPEUTIC OR PROPHYLACTIC SUBSTANCE", 
                            "38.02 INCISION OF OTHER VESSELS OF HEAD AND NECK"), `Interventions RH` = c("xray", 
                                                                                                        "CT Head", NA, NA, NA, NA, "CT Chest - Referring Hospital", "Chest Tube Placement", "Ct Head", 
                                                                                                        NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                        ))
```

As you can see, there are lots of mostly empty rows.  All of the mostly empty rows below a subjects name are associated with that subject.  I'd like to reshape my data set to be one row per subject, and I need some help.

I've looked at other answers on here for this, and I've asked my friends about it, and I keep seeing the "gather and then spread it" answer, but this particular situation is challenging me for a few specific reasons:

1. The rows are empty in the "full name" column that I'd usually key by.  I.e. I can't tell R to gather up all the Jane Smith rows, because they don't have her name in them.
2. There are several columns I want to spread out.  I would like to create multiple columns out of the "procedure performed" column, i.e. procedure1, procedure2, etc..   and I'd like to create multiple columns out of the "Interventions Rih" column.
3. I'm probably going to end up text searching the data for particular words or phrases during the analysis, so if the coding is easier to just squish every procedure for a particular patient into the "procedure performed" column for that patient (in one row), I'm ok with that too.

So for expected output, I am ok with either: 
[image]

or:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please show your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be pretty readily tackled with the newest updates to `tidyr v1.0.0`.

I'm also going to rename your columns so they are a bit easier to work with:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

sample_pivot_df <- sample2 %>% 
  # First renaming cols, but you can choose not to do this
  rename(full_name = `Full Name`,
         age = `Age 
                        (Y)`,
         gender = Gender,
         procedure = `Procedure Performed 
                        (ICD9 Code)`,
         intervention = `Interventions RH`) %>% 
  # Fill for repeated entries
  fill(full_name, age, gender) %>% 
  # Add a dummy column for number of procedures
  group_by(full_name) %>% 
  mutate(procedure_count = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # pivot the data wider for `procedure` and `intervention`
  pivot_wider(names_from = procedure_count,
              values_from = c(procedure, intervention))
```

Which gives us the following:

```
> sample_pivot_df
# A tibble: 2 x 15
  full_name age   gender procedure_1 procedure_2 procedure_3 procedure_4 procedure_5 procedure_6
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 Smith, J… 24    F      34.04 INSE… 86.59 CLOS… 87.03 COMP… 88.01 COMP… 87.41 COMP… NA         
2 Doe, John 22    M      96.04 INSE… 57.94 INSE… 99.29 INJE… 38.02 INCI… NA          NA         
# … with 6 more variables: intervention_1 <chr>, intervention_2 <chr>, intervention_3 <chr>,
#   intervention_4 <chr>, intervention_5 <chr>, intervention_6 <chr>
```

The caveat here is that using `tidyr::fill` may give you unintended results if any patients have an `NA` for `age` or `gender`.

Comment: absolutely need to rename, the column names I'm dealing with give me all sorts of other problems.  This solution is perfect, thank you.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend you check out the `janitor` package, particularly `janitor::clean_names`.  It was a lifesaver for dealing with healthcare data :)

Comment: I just noticed one slight problem. It absolutely splits the procedure and intervention columns into multiple columns as intended, and by filling the name column I know which procedure is associated with who, but it did not leave me with 1 row per subject.  Rather I have as many rows as that person had procedures.  Is there a way to "collapse" them down?  i.e. if one row has a blank for procedure2 but the next row has something.... squish those?  That make sense?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds as if (1) one of your columns did not get renamed appropriately, or (2) you have additional columns associated with procedures/interventions.  (1) Using the two columns in the `values_from` argument should collapse them down.  Make sure these names are correct.  (2)  IF you have additional columns associated with procedures/interventions, you will need to drop those, or include those in the `values_from` call as well

Comment: Im 99% sure everything was renamed correctly.  What do you mean by additional columns associated with procedures/interventions?  Sorry I'm dense, could you give me an example? And why that would cause problems?

Comment: No worries!  Are you encountering this issue with the `sample2` data provided?  If you are using a different dataset with additional columns, you likely will run into the issue you're describing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205258/discussion-between-dave-gruenewald-and-joe-crozier).

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using `data.table` for the aggregation and `zoo` to fill `NA` values. I've changed your column names to make the code more readable.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(sample2)
names(sample2) <- c("Name", "Age", "Gender", "Procedure", "Interventions")
sample2[, Name := na.locf(Name)] 


newSample = sample2[,.(
  Age = first(Age),
  Gender = first(Gender),
  aggProcedure = paste(Procedure[!is.na(Procedure)],collapse=","),
  aggInterventions = paste(Interventions[!is.na(Interventions)],collapse=",")), 

  by= Name]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in a much easier format first you use fill() function which fills null values with previous data, then you group your data and summarize it with pasting/concatenating it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sample2<-
  structure(list(
    `Full Name` = c("Smith, Jane", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Doe, John", NA, NA, NA), 
    `Age (Y)` = c("24", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "22", NA, NA, NA), 
    Gender = c("F", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, NA), 
    `Procedure Performed (ICD9 Code)` = 
      c("34.04 INSERTION OF INTERCOSTAL CATHETER FOR DRAINAGE",
        "86.59 CLOSURE OF SKIN AND SUBCUTANEOUS TISSUE OTHER SITES", 
        "87.03 COMPUTERIZED AXIAL TOMOGRAPHY OF HEAD", 
        "88.01 COMPUTERIZED AXIAL TOMOGRAPHY OF ABDOMEN", 
        "87.41 COMPUTERIZED AXIAL TOMOGRAPHY OF THORAX", 
        NA, 
        "96.04 INSERTION OF ENDOTRACHEAL TUBE",
        "57.94 INSERTION OF INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER", 
        "99.29 INJECTION OR INFUSION OF OTHER THERAPEUTIC OR PROPHYLACTIC SUBSTANCE", 
        "38.02 INCISION OF OTHER VESSELS OF HEAD AND NECK"), 
    `Interventions RH` = c("xray", "CT Head", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           "CT Chest - Referring Hospital", "Chest Tube Placement", 
                           "Ct Head", NA)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

new_sample <-
  sample2 %>%
  fill("Full Name") %>%
  fill("Age (Y)") %>%
  fill("Gender") %>%
  mutate(`Procedure Performed (ICD9 Code)` = replace_na(`Procedure Performed (ICD9 Code)`, ""),
         `Interventions RH` = replace_na(`Interventions RH`, "")) %>%
  group_by(`Full Name`, `Age (Y)`, `Gender`) %>%
  summarise(`Procedure Performed (ICD9 Code)` = 
              paste(`Procedure Performed (ICD9 Code)`, collapse =" "),
            `Interventions RH` = 
              paste(`Interventions RH`, collapse = " "))
```